# Java Script writer

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a Java Script that will allow me to to:

1. Close the Firefox Tab, after it has submitted the ad.
2. Open a new Firefox Tab with a different URL.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different things

Answer (score 0):

for opening a new tab use

```
<a href="www.exampleURL.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

and to close a tab use

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>
```

however the behaviour for opening and closing tabs can be over-ridden by most modern browsers so theres no guarantee that it will always work, also opening and closing tabs in a clients browser is a very good way of ensuring that users will avoid the screen. I personally find it one of the most annoying things a site can do. It's my browser I decide what gets opened in a new tab, new window or the same window, not the site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Now how would I code both of these together, open this one website address, then close this tab after ... seconds, then open this new website address called ...

I am sorry but I am new at this, so could you please let me know what exact JQuery code in total, I need to use? This all together.

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

ok so if it was me i would do something like

Static method:

```
function openLink() {
    window.open("www.example.com", '_blank');
}
```

or if you wanted it to be a bit more dynamic (so it can be used for multiple urls)

Dynamic method:

```
function openLink(url) {
    window.open(url , 'blank')
}
```

this function can then be called whenever you want it. as part of an onclick="" event or as part on another function
to call the static method use

```
openLink();
```

to call the dynamic method use

```
openLink("www.exampleURL.com");
```

now for closing the other screen. This is a little more tricky but as your using JQuery that simplifies this a little.

**In the script for the new tab** you first want to create whats commonly refered to as a "doc ready" function (at least where I work that's what is know as) in JQuery this is easy

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```

next we need to to use some sort of timing to delay the close, otherwise the tab will close as soon as the doc is ready (not useful) so i would use the setTimeout function as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 

    }, 3000);
});
```

the important part hear is the 3000. Its how many milliseconds need to pass before the function is run (1000 milliseconds == 1 second)

lastly we add the window.close to the function so it becomes this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        close_window();
    }, 3000);
});
```

As far as I Know you can't have a script from one page control another so you have to have part of the script to open the tab on the original tab and then the script to close the tab on the page that opens.
However if you are just using this to display info to the user or some similar type of use may I suggest that you investigate the .dialog() function from JQuery ui https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ its very versatile and quite easy to use as well. I hope that helps but if your sill struggling post your code on hear so we can have a look and see what can be worked out. Happy Coding.